# How to determine a string PARTIALLY contains another string ? (preferrable Java)

Tags: java, string, matching

I'm doing a java project which needs to determine whether a string contains another string following below logic:

- A parent string "This is a parent string" contais "isstr" should return true. Because all the characters of "isstr" can be found in parent string preserving substring order.
- contains should be case-insensitive.

Is there anyone could kindly help me how to write the logic in a simple and efficient way, or any library is also much appreciated!

Comment: Have u tried writing some code for this? Can u share that?

Comment: Try having a look at [`String#contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence))

Comment: to make it case insensitive, convert both string to the same case either by String.toUppercase() or String.toLowercase()

Comment: so far one method i know is to compile a regex pattern using Pattern.compile(). Insert ".*" into the begining, middle, and end of the substring. and compile with CASEInsensitive. But I feel it's a bit tedious and maybe not so efficient.  I hope there will be some better way of doing this...

Comment: the most straightforward way of turning this into a regex match is going to be at great risk for catastrophic backtracking

Comment: parentString.indexOf(character);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String parentStr = "This is a parent string", childStr = "iSStr";
    //Turn both to lowcase.
    parentStr.toLowerCase(); childStr.toLowerCase();
    Integer childStrIndex = 0;
    //Run over the parent string and if you found a match then keep comparing with the next
    //character in the child string.
    for (int index = 0 ; index < parentStr.length(); index++) {
        Character currChar = parentStr.charAt(index);
        if (childStr.length() <= childStrIndex)
            break;
        if (currChar.equals(childStr.charAt(childStrIndex)))
            childStrIndex++;
    }
    // If at the end you are in the last character of the child string, then is true.
    if (childStrIndex >= childStr.length())
        System.out.print(true);
    else
        System.out.print(false);
}
```

Hope this helps. BTW this sounds like homework.

Comment: Thank you very much ! This method looks much more efficient than regex mathing.
BTW this is not homework. :P

Answer (score 1):

Lets say "This is a parent string" is your parent string. and "isstr" is query string.

For case insensitive matching, convert both parent string and query string to lowercase.

You can split parent string into keywords and look for each keyword into the query string.

Reverse the query string ("isstr") and push it onto a stack, since you would like to preserve the order.

```
Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();
String reversedQueryString = new StringBuilder(queryString).reverse().toString();
for (char ch: reversedQueryString.toCharArray()) {
    stack.push(ch);
}
```

Pop out alphabets from the query string, when they match alphabets in the parent string. Stack is useful in this case, as we don't care if the same characters are found again.

```
String[] keywords = parentString.split(" "); \\ to split on spaces.
for(String keyword : keywords){
    processKeyword(keyword);
}

void processKeyword(String keyword){
    for (char c: keyword.toCharArray()) {
        if(stack.top().equals(c)){
            stackCheck();
        }  
    } 
}

void stackCheck(){
    if(!stack.isEmpty())
       stack.pop();
    else{
       System.out.println("Eureka");

    }
}
```

This is just an example, your implementation can vary. For example you might want to check for two characters in a keyword to believe its partially contains the query string.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works in similar way of @astinx answer, but control substring index in a stack instead of integer index++. I'm not sure which one works faster but this one look a little bit more verbose.

Comment: Like I said, its just an example. You can further improve the code and make it more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

It could be as simple as this:

```
public boolean contains(final String base, final String search){
    final String baseLowerCase = base.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
    for(final char c : search.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH).toCharArray())
        if(baseLowerCase.indexOf(c) < 0)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

For example: `contains("This is a parent string", "isstr");` returns `true`.

What you are pretty much trying to do here is convert the `String` you're searching for in to a `char[]` in which you will be iterated upon. Then you want to check to see if the base `String` contains that `char` (using `String#indexOf(char)`). You want to return `false` on the first occurrence that it does not contain the `char` (meaning `String#indexOf(char)` returns a value < 0)

Comment: But returns `false` if you use `iSStr` instead of `isstr`, doesn't should be case insensitive?

Comment: it also doesn't respect the order of search like the op wants. see http://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/java_visualize/#code=public+class+ClassNameHere+%7B%0A++++public+static+void+main(String%5B%5D+args)+%7B%0A+++++++contains(%22This+is+a+parent+string%22,+%22iTstr%22)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A+++public+static+boolean+contains(final+String+base,+final+String+search)%7B%0A++++for(final+char+c+%3A+search.toCharArray())%0A++++++++if(base.indexOf(c)+%3C+0)%0A++++++++++++return+false%3B%0A++++return+true%3B%0A%7D%0A%7D&mode=display&curInstr=15

Answer (score 0):

The search is going to involve backtracking, so if you are going to implement this by hand then a recursive solution is probably warranted.

But a simple approach would be to pre-process the input string into a regex, and then do a regex "find".  For instance, if the search string is "instr" then the regex could be `"[iI].*[nN].*[sS].*[tT].*[rR]"`.

Note that this search is inevitably going to be expensive, and even more so if it is done with a regex.  In fact a naive implementation is `O(M^N)` where `M` is the length of the input string and `N` is the length of the search string.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is the same as my initial thinking. I also think it's a big expensive.