# Compare two Strings in java

Tags: java

I want to compare two Strings in java and i need ans "yes" for below code.Here i have used contains function.

```
  String String1="2014-08-12 09:00:00";
  String String2="2014-08 09:00:00";

   if(String1.contains(String2)){
       System.out.println(" yes ");
   }else{
       System.out.println(" no ");
   }
```

contains function is unable to do that. What should i code? this is sample.. Actually i am comparing String1 with an list of contents.

I need help.

Comment: I'm afraid you're actually going to have to do that terrible thing called "programming".

Comment: `boolean compare(String s1, String s2) { return "yes"; }` There, I made a function to your specs. Now how about you properly formulate what you need and what you tried?

Comment: Compare two strings based on what? Tokens ?

Comment: look at what methods pop up when you put a dot after String1.... you might see something useful

Comment: check if the format of strings is always same, split string2 and test if string1 contains 1st token AND contains 2nd token, print yes else print no.

Comment: If you want to compare the year and month alone, and the format of the string remain same, why couldn't you get the substring and use equals

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are trying to compare between two Dates , Try This :

```
 SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:dd");
        String String1 = "2014-08-12 09:00:00";
        String String2 = "2014-08 09:00:00";

        Date date1 = formatter.parse(String1);
        formatter.applyPattern("yyyy-MM HH:mm:dd");
        Date date2 = formatter.parse(String2);

        if(date1.equals(date2)){
            System.out.println(" yes ");
        }else{
            System.out.println(" no ");
        }
```

Comment: what's the difference b/w my code and your code???? (except variable names and the print statement)

Comment: @PurbaDasMoumi add throws  Exception after your function name for example : public static void main(String[] args) throws  Exception{

Comment: thank u so much :) ...this works..u have saved me from programming.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Write your own parser function. On the top of my mind I can think you can do

1. Create a HashMap. Iterate over the 1st String. Store each character as key and no of occurrence of that character as the value.
2. Now iterate on the second String. For each character get the value from Hashmap. If it is 0 return No else reduce the value by 1.
3. If end of second String is reached return Yes.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to partially compare Strings to see if one is contained in another. If you want to partially compare Strings to see if they are equal, you can use this method from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19216511/2591612):

```
public boolean contains(final String base, final String search){
    final String baseLowerCase = base.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
    for(final char c : search.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH).toCharArray())
        if(baseLowerCase.indexOf(c) < 0)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Note, that this isn't foolproof. Ideally you would want to set some sort of threshold instead of just being equal to 1 character. It also doesn't check if the characters are in the same locations in both Strings.